# How to print text field data in report format?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a simple application using win forms C# in which simple text fields receive data from the user.
Now i want to print that fields data in report format keeping in mind i am not using any database.
How can i do that? if it's too simple then i am sorry, i am just a beginner.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "report format" ?

Comment: means a report like any super store bill

Comment: what do you have so far? where are you stuck ?

Comment: i haven't any idea how to build report, i have tried crystal report but how to pass data to it? it is asking for database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Reports. Data source doesn't have to be database, you can use object from your solution.
Useful links:

- [Object data source](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/objectdatasources/index.html)
- [General info](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/)